502 Errors via Google Cloud-Run When Request Returns >64KiB JSON, Compressed?
I'm having a problem with my service running under Google's Cloud-Run sending 502 responses for large API responses.
My (Angular) frontend app sends a JSON formatted request to my (Kotlin+Ktor) Cloud-Run service and gets a JSON formatted response.  Everything works fine... until the response exceeds 64KiB in length, then it suddenly becomes an immediate "502 Bad Gateway" response.
There are no log messages from my service even though I have exception handlers that would show a failure.  I get only this in the Cloud-Run "logs" tab:
POST 502 135 B 175 ms Chrome 126 https://my-service.com/api/LargeResponseCall

Everything looks good on my service.  I've added code to log the request & response and everything appears correct meaning the problem is either in Ktor or Cloud-Run.
When I run the container on my local machine, I don't encounter any problems which tells me it's not a Ktor issues. (Unless the HTTP request created by Cloud-Run is somehow different than the one created by Chrome.)
I send plenty of other data larger than 64KiB but only the JSON response is having problems.  I have configured no gateways, proxies, or intermediate servers and there is nothing special about the /api/ handlers.
Is there a limit in Cloud-Run?  How can I debug this?
Update1: I changed the response type from application/json to application/octet-stream and now the large responses work just fine.
Update2: Here is a capture from Google Cloud-Trace:

Update3: I have traced the trigger for this problem to my Ktor compression configuration:
    install(Compression) {
        gzip {
            priority = 1.0
            matchContentType(
                ContentType.Application.Json,
            )
        }
    }


When this is in place, I get 502 errors under Google Cloud-Run for uncompressed content >64KiB.  I do not get them when running the container locally under Docker.  If I remove this config then it works in both places, albeit without the desired compression.
Here's what I think is happening:

Ktor, when doing compression, streams the output without setting a Content-Length header. I can see this, for responses that don't fail, on the Chrome side.  No such header is sent.
The Ktor compression (or perhaps the gzip library) is operating in 64KiB chunks.  It takes 64KiB at a time from the response, compresses it, and sends it out the network.
The Cloud-Run frontend receives the first compressed chunk but does not wait for additional data, instead failing with a 502 back to the client.

This explains why:

Responses <64KiB work fine -- they are only one output chunk long.
Pre-compressed gzip files are sent with a content-length, so they work fine.

One side or the other is doing something wrong here.  Either Cloud-Run is not handling the missing Content-Length correctly or Ktor is not specifying something it "must" that Chrome tolerates but Cloud-Run does not.

As per the update I could see your issue is resolved. Can you post your solution as answer for better community visibility.

It wouldn't say it's "resolved".  I've "worked around the problem".  I'd like to know the root cause so I can fix that (or the bug on Cloud-Run can be fixed so others don't hit this).

If you are using load balancer , Can you share the statusDetails  field of the load balancer logs.

I've never configured anything like that.  The "Load Balancers", "Backends", and "Frontends" tabs are all empty.  The "LB Policies" tab shows the API isn't enabled.  I checked the YAML for my service and "balanc" appears nowhere.  My service isn't even yet public so there isn't significant traffic that would cause anything automatic to happen.

Can you share complete error logs?

There are no error logs that I can find other than the "POST 502" line (included in the report) in my "LOGS" tab.  My service reports a successful send of the full response; no thrown exceptions.  When the response size is just under 64KiB, it works.  When it's just over 64KiB, it fails with 502.  (Unless I change the response type away from application/json, something that I'd expect changes only the behavior of the client, not the network.)

There is an HTTP1.1 (!) limit of 32MiB but this exceeds your experience (and you're probably using HTTP2). You can't avoid Google Frontends etc. when you deploy to Cloud Run but I think it unlikely this is the source of your issue. I created a simple service that returns x KiB JSON responses on request and this continues to work well beyond (stopped trying) at 512 KiB. If not already, it would be interesting to add logging for the steps upto and including the generation of the JSON response so that you can inspect these values

Cloud Trace may provide insights too but I'm unsure how this works with Kotlin/Java.

Seems like cloud run does not throw 502 exception looks like you have an issue at your Http handling config in your code, However, You can contact support to know where the issue lies.

Cloud-Trace capture added.  It could be an issue with my app's http handling but since I have no troubles with it running under Docker on my home workstation, any such problem is an interaction between it and Google's frontend (doing TLS, etc.)  This makes sense given that "502 Bad Gateway" means "the server, while acting as a gateway or proxy, received an invalid response from the upstream server."  The question is: Why is my server's application/json response valid when <64KiB but invalid when >64KiB?

It's tedious but, one way to diagnose this would be to gradually remove components of your app until it works. My repro can ship 128KiB (simple) JSON and we know this should work. So, by one-by-one eliminating elements (or adding them back), you should be able to find the culprit. Can you capture a >64KiB JSON response and send it as a literal|constant from your app's server?

Difficult to do but the idea did get me thinking.  The one related thing is that I have compression enabled in the Ktor config for only application/json. And guess what? When I remove that, it again works with the original content-type and (uncompressed) results >64KiB. But again, I get no problems with compression (Chrome shows "content-encoding:gzip") running the container under Docker locally; it fails only on Cloud-Run.  I have other, bigger files that are pre-compressed and sent with "content-encoding:gzip"; they work just fine everywhere.

I guess from the silence I'll assume of that this a bug in the Google frontends.

For what it's worth, the GFE also aborts with a 502 if I try to set too many cookies.  Yes, I know it's a bad design on my part, one I had planned to address, but why is the GFE even processing this!

I know it's frustrating to feel you're not being heard but you probably aren't., If you want to engage Google on this issue, you'll need to talk to Cloud Support. Google redirects developers to Stack overflow but -- IMO -- that's not because Google Engineering participates here as much as it's easy to offload issues onto the community.

I tried that.  It shows "Your current Customer Care service: Basic (billing-only)" and then it sends me here.  The thing is...  I worked for Google for 15y and I understand that they're overwhelmed with "bugs" so unless it affects a large number of customers (or a very big customer), they tend to just be ignored.  I've fixed the bad design that created large numbers of cookies but still can't enable compression of the JSON replies; that should be something they care to fix.

I think "sending people here" is a way to abrogate the issue. Have you tried Issue Tracker? But yes, if you really want to get a support engineer on this, you need to pay Google to help them fix their issues.

I think it's this:
https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/298945253
